# solve for variable in combination

Tags: combinatorics

i have the combination ${n\choose 11}=12376$ and am looking to solve for $n$.  it turns out to be $17$.  of course can use brute force approach where just plug numbers in for $n$ but am looking for a cleaner method?

so ${{n!}\over {11!(n-11)!}}=12376$

$n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-10)=11!(12376)$

by the pigeonhole principle can eliminate $10!$ and be left with

$n(something)=11(12376)=11(2^3)(7)(13)(17)$

thanks.

Comment: very good answers.  thanks.  checked/voted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(n-10)^{11}<n(n-1)\cdots(n-10)<n^{11}$$ so $$\root{11}\of{11!(12376)}<n<\root{11}\of{11!(12376)}+10$$ So that just gives you a few values of $n$ to try, and I'd recommend starting in the middle of that range.

Answer (score 2):

As an approximation, I would note that the AM-GM gives
$$
\begin{align}
12376
&=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-9)(n-10)}{11!}\\
&\lesssim\frac{(n-5)^{11}}{11!}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
n\gtrsim5+(11!\cdot12376)^{1/11}=16.5629
$$
Trying $n=17$ gives $\binom{17}{11}=12376$